Auto Fill Pre-Enagement in Flex webchat 3.0
I am using Flex Webchat 3.0 and its working fine but I want to auto fill or just skip the form, sending values from my own. So, we know whoever is asking for help, we know who they are from our system and help them.
I am using Vuejs and I have used CDN link that is provided by the console.
Here is a snippet of code
<script>
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
          const appConfig = {
             //deploymentKey: "-----------"
          }
          
          Twilio.initWebchat(appConfig); 
        })

</script>

from the network tab i observed that I am sending
DeploymentKey:
CustomerFriendlyName: test
PreEngagementData: {"friendlyName":"test","email":"test@example.com","query":"testing"}
Identity:
I tried messing with PreEngagementData and I had no luck.
I want to send these PreEngagementData myself, not taking it from user and skip the PreEngagementForm so when the user utilize the chat, he sees messaging area
